# displaying webpage content

Tags: java, android, eclipse, web

Basically what i am trying to do is display webpage content from some webpage in TextView. When I run this app it does not crash , but it does not show anything? What am I doing wrong?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  }

  public void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {

    URL oracle = new URL("http://www.pocketnow.com");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(oracle.openStream()));

    String inputLine;
    TextView prikazTeksta = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
    {
      prikazTeksta.setText(inputLine.toString());
    }
    in.close();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
  {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
  {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings)
    {
      return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }
}
```

Comment: Eclipse is used to develop all sorts of things so please set a tag telling us what you are developing. I have added the android tag as that seems to be what you are doing. If you don't set useful tags the people who can answer the question probably won't see it.

Answer (score 0):

TextView.setText() replaces all contents, perhaps you want TextView.append()

Also a WebView may be more appropriate for what you want?

Answer (score 0):

*public void main* does not exist in Android. It doesn't get called automatically, you must call it yourself. And you can't display web content in a TextView like that. There's a component called WebView for this job. Just remove *main*, replace your TextView in XML with a WebView and use this code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.lyout.activity_main);
    WebView prikazTeksta = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    prikazTeksta.loadUrl("http://www.pocketnow.com");
}

...
```

Comment: It crashes now, logcat says : Unable to start activity ComponentInfo

Comment: Well, wasn't my goal to correct what odd things you're trying to do. An exception is thrown because you can't open a stream to a URL like that. And what's the point of that anyway? You'd display the page's HTML. Just use a WebView and its method *loadUrl*.

Comment: I want to do what I wrote, display webpage content. Like some news apps that get content from their news webpage

Comment: WebView.loadUrl(...) does that. Exactly that. Use it instead of your TextView. Check my updated answer. Be aware that I changed the ID to webView, so you have to do that in your XML, too.

Comment: Add <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> to your AndroidManifest.xml, right below the <manifest> tag.